# Codeigniter - Custom result object method accessing to non-public properties...without setter?

Tags: codeigniter, object, model

I just working on some project for my client, and probably I found some bug or missleading description in documentation.

I want to make a model, what is rerning results by custom classes, so I'm using custom_row_object method.

```
class UserModel extends CI_Model {

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('Class_loader'); /custom spl loader
}

public function get_user_by_email($email, $password = null){
    $this->db->where('email',$email);
    $result = $this->db->get('User');
    return $result->custom_row_object(0,'User');
}

}
```

and here is my class

```
class User {

private $idUser;
private $password;
private $email;
private $role;

public function __construct() {
    echo 'instancja';
    echo $this->password;
}

public function __set($name, $value) {

    if ($name === 'password') {
        $this->password = '****' // only for testing purposes :)

}
}

}
```

based on information [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#custom-result-objects) I understand that CI shouldn't have access to this properties directly, and should call a __set method.

But I'm so confused, because there is no any custom constructor, and my __set method should modify only a password property - but it won't, CI returns object with already setted properties directly from database! The only thing what I can do to modify them is adding a constructor and made changes in it like this

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->password = '****';
}
```

So the question is - how it's possible? Is CI uses some reflection mechanism, or am I too stupid and I understood docs wrong ? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the answer in the underlying Driver.

You probably use mysql as database and pdo / mysqli as a driver.

In both cases - Codeigniter uses the `fetchObject` (PDO) or `fetch_object` (MySQLi) methods.
You can find this lines of code for PDO [here](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/drivers/pdo/pdo_result.php#L195) and for MySQLi [here](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_result.php#L229) on the official Codeigniter Github Repository.

If you take a look on the documentation now - it cleary states

**PDO:**

> When an object is fetched, its properties are assigned from respective column values, and afterwards its constructor is invoked.

**MySQLi:**

> The mysqli_fetch_object() will return the current row result set as an object where the attributes of the object represent the names of the fields found within the result set.
>
> Note that mysqli_fetch_object() sets the properties of the object before calling the object constructor.

Source - PHP Documentation:

[PDOStatement::fetchObject](https://www.php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetchobject.php)

[mysqli_result::fetch_object](https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php)

Comment: That's what I'm looking for - thanks ;) Looks like I need to learn more :)